# How to make LinearLayout in Visual Basic (visual studio 2013)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

(this is not related to VB6)

[image]

like above, I want to make a 'textbox' control between separated 'label' controls.

I used method to load those three controls (two labels and one textbox), but I cannot precisely locate the textbox and the following label.

In the application, there will be more than hundreds of sentences with almost the same number of blanks(textbox), so the perfect lining is required.

So, is there any good method to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: there are lots of options.  if the user cannot actually edit the Textbox, just use a single label and `String.Format` to insert the 'subject'.  With that many instances, consider building a UserCOntrol of 2 labels and a text box, then just add one for each sentence; or create a class which creates the controls dynamically (turn autosize off) and locates them.

Comment: How long are your sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a class that inherits from Panel and includes two Labels and a Textbox that get automatically realigned. I did something like that to get you started. Just paste the code into your project, recompile once and you can add these to your Form from the Toolbox (or create them dynamically of course). This is nowhere complete. You should make properties for the fonts for example and additional events based on your needs but you get my idea I think.

```
Public Class ctrlBlankSentence
    Inherits Panel
    Private WithEvents lblLeft As Label 'The left part of the sentence
    Private WithEvents tbBlank As TextBox 'The blank text
    Private WithEvents lblRight As Label 'The right part of the sentence
    Public Event BlankTextChanged() 'Use events to react to user input
    Private _Spacing As Integer
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines the distance between the labels and the textbox
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Spacing As Integer
        Get
            Return _Spacing
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _Spacing = value
            DoreAlign()
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _TextboxWidth As Integer
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines the width of the textbox
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property TextboxWidth As Integer
        Get
            Return _TextboxWidth
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _TextboxWidth = value
            DoreAlign()
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _AutosizeControl As Boolean
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines if the panel is automatically resized.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property AutosizeControl As Boolean
        Get
            Return _AutosizeControl
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _AutosizeControl = value
            DoreAlign()
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used to get or set the left part of the sentence
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property LeftText As String
        Get
            Return lblLeft.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            lblLeft.Text = value
            DoreAlign()
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used to set the right part of the sentence
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property RightText As String
        Get
            Return lblRight.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            lblRight.Text = value
            DoreAlign()
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used to get or set the user input
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property BlankText As String
        Get
            Return tbBlank.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            tbBlank.Text = value
            RaiseEvent BlankTextChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

#Region "Constructor"
    Public Sub New()
        lblLeft = New Label With {.AutoSize = True, .Text = "Left Text"}
        lblRight = New Label With {.AutoSize = True, .Text = "Right Text"}
        tbBlank = New TextBox
        Spacing = 3
        TextboxWidth = 100
        AutosizeControl = True
        Me.Controls.Add(lblLeft)
        Me.Controls.Add(lblRight)
        Me.Controls.Add(tbBlank)
        DoreAlign()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "The method the realigns the controls"
    Private Sub DoreAlign()
        lblLeft.Left = 0
        tbBlank.Left = lblLeft.Right + Spacing
        tbBlank.Width = TextboxWidth
        lblRight.Left = tbBlank.Right + Spacing
        If AutosizeControl Then
            Me.Width = lblRight.Right
            Me.Height = tbBlank.Height
        End If
        lblRight.Top = CInt(Me.Height / 2 - lblRight.Height / 2)
        lblLeft.Top = lblRight.Top
    End Sub
#End Region

    Private Sub thisTextChanged() Handles tbBlank.TextChanged
        RaiseEvent BlankTextChanged()
    End Sub
End Class
```